# why cookie is set in response but session in request?

Tags: django, session, cookies, request, response

I know how `session` and `cookies` work. I am doing an online course on `django` where a function for setting language preference in `session` and `cookie` is written in `views.py`. I do not understand why `cookie` is set on `response` but `session` on `request`. The instructor mentioned it works the same in `PHP` or any other `web framework`.

but he did not explain why? can some one explain why?

Here is the function:

```
def language(request,language=“en-us”):
    response=HttpResonse(“setting language to %s” %language)

    response.set_cookie(‘lang’,language)
    request.session[‘lang’]=language

    return response
```

Answer (score 0):

I will talk about Java but it shall be similar in django. Session attributes are accesible in servlets and jsp in similar way like request parameters. You can look at it like server side stored request parameters. Some frameworks like JSF even use request scope to store session variable. So basicly you can look at session as request decorator which puts value stored in web container.

Comment: request parameters must be on client side rather than server side correct?

Comment: Request paramaters are attributes of HTTP request, typically encoded in URL or passed in request body. They can come either from from or manualy constructed in link (URL part after ?). Session attributes are used by website developer to store session, typically user token, eshop cart content etc. Server associates request with session via cookie or it may be encoded in URL parameter as well.

Comment: yes, that is correct. but I am not still clear as how session operates on requests and cookies on response, my question above..

Comment: Cookie - you instruct to write cookie to output stream, therefore it is response. Contrary received cookies are taken from input stream and therefore you get then from request.

Comment: Session - you create variable that can be used during processing of current request. As side effect cookie / URL rewrite may be generated. Sorry, I cannot explain it better.

Comment: These variables are associated with request, they enhance it. Therefore API authors chose request and not response.